# What is the correct way to use static functions?

Tags: c, function, call

I have this code, which works, but I don't think I'm doing it the right way. I have 3 files, `main.c`, `init.c` and `init.h`.

`init.h` file looks like this (I omitted preprocessor directives in this example for simplicity):

```
void init(int param);

int firstCFG(int param);
int secondCFG(int param);
int thirdCFG(int param);
int fourthCFG(int param);
int fifthCFG(int param);
```

and the `init.c` file looks like this:

```
#include "init.h"

void init(int param){
   int cfg1 = firstCFG(1);
   int cfg2 = secondCFG(2);
   int cfg3 = thirdCFG(3);
   int cfg4 = fourtCFG(4);
   int cfg5 = fifthCFG(5);
}

int firstCFG(int param){
   //do stuff
   return stuff;
}
int secondCFG(int param){
   //do stuff
   return stuff;
}
int thirdCFG(int param){
   //do stuff
   return stuff;
}
int fourthCFG(int param){
   //do stuff
   return stuff;
}
int fifthCFG(int param){
   //do stuff
   return stuff;
}
```

and from my `main.c` file I call it like this:

```
#include "init.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    init(0);

    //do stuff....
}
```

So basically, I call only one function in `init.c` - `init();` and other functions within that file are called from that file itself. But since I included `init.h` in the main file, I can call all CFG functions from main but I don't want to be able to. I want `main.c` file to see only the `init()` function and CFG functions to be private for the `init.c`. So my question is, what is the right way to do this?

My initial though was to make the CFG functions `static` and don't do `#include "init.h"` in `main.c` so only `init()` is extern. That worked too but the the compiler gave me warning `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘init’`

Comment: If you don't want to call the `CFG` functions from other files, what is your reasoning for declaring them in `init.h`?

Comment: Curiously you ask about static functions but none of your functions are `static`. Simply change the CFG functions to be `static int *CFG(…)` in `init.c` and they won't be visible outside that compilation unit. (Of course this contradicts declaring them in `init.h`, so remove those and only leave the `void init(int)`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd put *only* the `void init(int param);` prototype in `init.h`. Make all the CFG functions `static` in init.c.

You will still need prototypes for the CFG functions (unless you move `init()` to the end), but you could just declare them in `init.c`. Or you could put them in a separate `init_impl.h` file that is not available for users of your module to `#include`.

Comment: You may get a compiler diagnostic `missing-declarations` if you don't have prototypes for your functions and they aren't `static`.